# Using method override in iOS jailbreak dev

Tags: ios, jailbreak, theos

I was trying to override setFrame: function and my code looks like this:

```
%new
- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];
}
```

But I got an error from compiler:

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'super'
    [super setFrame:frame];
     ^
1 error generated.
```

I've tried using [[[UIView alloc] init] setFrame:frame];  but it didn't work.

Edit:
I'm using THEOS

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing %new and add an %orig in the function, that work for me in this case.